# Forbidden words library available?

Tags: android, native

Is there a library in Android for us to use to validate forbidden words during form submission ?

Trying to validate forbidden words in native android code. Do we have to write custom code and maintain a list of bad words to be validated

Comment: You can search for "profanity filter".

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of forbidden words, Implement validation logic, Integrate validation into your form submission process and Consider third-party libraries